# unix sed command for escaped chars

Tags: unix, sed

I try to replace the char `#` with a newline `\n`:

```
sed -e "s/#/\n/g" > file.txt
```

this works fine.

Now there is problem with the char `#`, when is escaped with `-`:

eg.: 123#456-#789#777 should be:
123
456#789
777

The escaped char `-` itself can also be escaped:
eg.: 123#456-#789--012#777 should be:
123
456#789-012
777

How can i do this with sed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "123#456-#789#777" | sed 's/\([^-]\)#/\1\n/g;s/-\(.\)/\1/g'
123
456#789
777

$ echo "123#456-#789--012#777" | sed 's/\([^-]\)#/\1\n/g;s/-\(.\)/\1/g'
123
456#789-012
777

$ echo "#123#456-#789#777" | sed 's/\(^\|[^-]\)#/\1\n/g;s/-\(.\)/\1/g'

123
456#789
777

$ echo "#1###2-#3--4#5#" | sed "s/\([^-]\)##/\1#\n/g;s/\(^\|[^-]\)#/\1\n/g;s/-\(.\)/\1/g" 

1


2#3-4
5

$
```

First part is to preserve `-<any chars>` and convert `#` (without the preceding `-`) to newline, second part is to convert `-<any chars>` to only `<any chars>` (If you don't need such wildcard, I think you know how to modify for only `-` and `#`.)

Comment: what about echo "#123#456-#789#777" | sed 's/\\([^-]\\)#/\1\n/g;s/-\\(.\\)/\1/g'

Comment: @newGuest, are you expecting a newline before '123'? Then sed 's/\\(^\|[^-]\\)#/\1\n/g;s/-\\(.\\)/\1/g' is what you want.

Comment: the newline CAN be there - but this dont work: echo "1##2#3" | sed "s/\\(^\|[^-]\\)#/\1\n/g;s/-\\(.\\)/\1/g"

Comment: @newGuest, could you edit your question for the expected result for the case?

Comment: "#1##2#3" should be: <LF>1<LF><LF>2<LF>3 - so every 'normal' # should be a newline (<LF>)

Answer (score 0):

sed -e "s/([^-])#/\1\n/g;s/--/-/g;s/-#/#/g"

This only escapes -- and -# though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "123#456-#789--012#777" | awk -F"#" '{print $1;for(i=2;i<NF-1;i++){printf "%s#",$i};print $(NF-1);print $NF}'
123
456-#789--012
777
$ echo "123#456-#789#777" | awk -F"#" '{print $1;for(i=2;i<NF-1;i++){printf "%s#",$i};print $(NF-1);print $NF}'
123
456-#789
777
```